# How do I download an ubuntu dsc file?

Tags: git, ubuntu

I am trying to implement a work around with git. In order to do so I am going to this page [LaunchPad Git](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/git/1:2.10.2-2) and am attempting to download this file git_2.10.2-2.dsc. I need this specific file in order for the work around to work. However, when I click this file to begin to download I am redirected to a page that has this:

```
-----BEGIN PGP SIGNED MESSAGE-----
Hash: SHA256

Format: 3.0 (quilt)
Source: git
Binary: git, git-man, git-core, git-doc, git-arch, git-cvs, git-svn, git-mediawiki, git-email, git-daemon-run, git-daemon-sysvinit, git-gui, gitk, git-el, gitweb, git-all
Architecture: any all
Version: 1:2.10.2-2
Maintainer: Gerrit Pape <pape@smarden.org>
Uploaders: Jonathan Nieder <jrnieder@gmail.com>, Anders Kaseorg <andersk@mit.edu>
Homepage: https://git-scm.com/
Standards-Version: 3.9.6.0
Vcs-Browser: http://repo.or.cz/w/git/debian.git/
Vcs-Git: https://repo.or.cz/r/git/debian.git/
Build-Depends: libz-dev, libpcre3-dev, gettext, libcurl4-gnutls-dev, libexpat1-dev, subversion, libsvn-perl, libyaml-perl, tcl, libhttp-date-perl | libtime-modules-perl, python, cvs, cvsps, libdbd-sqlite3-perl, unzip, libio-pty-perl, debhelper (>= 9), dh-exec (>= 0.7), dh-apache2, dpkg-dev (>= 1.16.2~)
Build-Depends-Indep: asciidoc, xmlto, docbook-xsl
Package-List:
 git deb vcs optional arch=any
 git-all deb vcs optional arch=all
 git-arch deb vcs optional arch=all
 git-core deb vcs optional arch=all
 git-cvs deb vcs optional arch=all
 git-daemon-run deb vcs optional arch=all
 git-daemon-sysvinit deb vcs extra arch=all
 git-doc deb doc optional arch=all
 git-el deb vcs optional arch=all
 git-email deb vcs optional arch=all
 git-gui deb vcs optional arch=all
 git-man deb doc optional arch=all
 git-mediawiki deb vcs optional arch=all
 git-svn deb vcs optional arch=all
 gitk deb vcs optional arch=all
 gitweb deb vcs optional arch=all
Checksums-Sha1:
 2023975ae0061bd569b8529025428e3eca53be2e 4106108 git_2.10.2.orig.tar.xz
 00d7776b0dd941c4b5e7ee1041b860a3dce4697d 511468 git_2.10.2-2.debian.tar.xz
Checksums-Sha256:
 94802903dd707d85ca3b9a2be35e936a54ce86375f52c6a789efe7ce7e238671 4106108 git_2.10.2.orig.tar.xz
 6b39f43c310f756042769f7aa72e1f8a6859192f28f9fedc3435514977738cdb 511468 git_2.10.2-2.debian.tar.xz
Files:
 3cd1dca37be60668f482545716923b72 4106108 git_2.10.2.orig.tar.xz
 336a35cbe1f1d6b04375cd87a302eb06 511468 git_2.10.2-2.debian.tar.xz

-----BEGIN PGP SIGNATURE-----
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=ngpD
-----END PGP SIGNATURE-----
```

All it is is text on a webpage git 2.10 dsc file. Is this how this file is supposed to be? What exactly do I do with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That text is in fact the content of the dsc file. If you save it, and do the same for the associated `.orig.tar.xz` and `.debian.tar.xz` files, then run `dpkg-source -x git_2.10.2-2.dsc` to extract them.

If you have a `deb-src` entry in your `/etc/apt/sources.list` you can do all the downloading and unpacking in one command: `apt-get source git`.

Next you'll probably want to know how to build the thing... I get the feeling you're at the beginning of a process that is longer than you think it is, and there will be a lot more questions before you're done, and maybe you should explain your overall goal so someone can tell whether your plan makes any sense at all.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @Wumpus Q. Wumbley.  
I am trying to follow the steps found in this stackoverflow answer askubuntu.com/questions/186847/… to rebuild git 2.10.2 with `openssl` instead of `gnutls`. In order to do so I need the .dsc file to run dpkg-source -x

Comment: Well, you got the dsc file. It's right there in your question. Everything from `-----BEGIN PGP SIGNED MESSAGE-----` to `-----END PGP SIGNATURE-----`. That's it. So really this is a "how do I download a text file" question?